# flow network proof with cuts in it

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

I’m currently studying flow networks in the university, and my professor presented this theorem to us:
“Given a flow network, and a flow B in it, so that for each vertex, except the source and the sink: **|**∑(e:u→v) of B(e) **-** ∑(e':v→u) of B(e')**|**≤ε.

> Note: this equation is for every v (vertex who is not the source or
>   the sink in the network). e:u→v means that I want the Sum of B(e)'s of
>   every edge who is, in a cutset, from the set of u to the set of v. and
>   then, e':v→u means that I want the Sum of B(e)'s of every edge who is,
>   in the same cutset, from the set of v to the set of u.

There exists a new flow, F, that for every edge in the graph, |F(e)-B(e)|<ε*N (where N is the number of vertexes in the graph).”

He claimed that a proof exists, but I can’t get to the bottom of it. I was thinking about the fact that Epsilon’s lower bound is the min cut of the graph, but all the other ideas I had we’re useless. I’d appreciate any help. I searched for the proof on the web but couldn’t find anything.

Thanks in advance,
Or

Comment: Given the way you stated this |∑(e:u→v) of B(e) - ∑(e':v→u) of B(e')| = 0, since ∑(e:u→v) of B(e) =  ∑(e':v→u) of B(e'). That is, both those sums are exactly the same, you've just swapped the use of v and u, but you never make mention of what v or u are. I think you need to much more clear with your question to get an answer.

Comment: v and u are vertexes in the network.
this is not the same because it's in a differrent ways.

Comment: Okay... let me make more explicit what I meant. Since u,v are unspecified nodes used as indices in a summation then ∑(e:u→v) of B(e) = ∑(e':v→u) of B(e) in the same sense that ∫f(x)dx = ∫f(y)dy. Your use of notation is an abuse of notation that obscures what you are trying to ask. Specify explicitly and more clearly what the summations are being taken over. Probably one of u,v is meant to be fixed? Better yet, just write in words what e and e' are supposed to be since your having difficulty writing it in notation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more clear.
So, this equation is for every v (vertex who is not the source or the sink in the network). e:u→v means that I want the Sum of B(e)'s of every edge who is, in a cutset, from the set of u to the set of v.
and then, e':v→u means that I want the Sum of B(e)'s of every edge who is, in the same cutset, from the set of v to the set of u.

Comment: You should edit the question to say that instead, it is much clearer and you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I added this explanation. Hopefully I'll get an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given an antisymmetric assignment of quantities to edges, the *excess* of a vertex is the total quantity entering minus the total quantity exiting. For each vertex v with a negative excess -c, choose a path from the source s to v, multiply it by c, and add it to the assignment. For each vertex v with a positive excess c, choose a path from v to the sink t, multiply it by c, and add it to the assignment. It's straightforward to check that (1) all of the excesses are now zero, except at s and t (2) since every excess was less than epsilon in absolute value, the worst-case change for an edge is if it's involved in every path, for a total of less than epsilon times n, the number of vertices.

Comment: as I understand it, the excess of every vertex should be zero from the beginning, no?
edit: I understood your answer and actually I think it's as you wrote. probably, the excess doesn't have to be zero in the beginning.

Thank you!

Comment: I succeed to get all of the excesses to zero with another way:
after I choose a path, I don't multiply it by c, but adding c to every edge. In this way, it works.